# How to attach an image directly inside iOS Mail app while writing an e-mail?

Tags: ios, email, photos, mobile-mail, attachments

When I want to send an image from my iPhone 4s, the workflow is easy. I go to Pictures, I pick the target image and then I click on the "share" icon in bottom left corner. Then of course I can add additional message and my e-mail with attachment is ready to be send.

[image]

That's fine but what if I'm for example writing just a plain text e-mail. I'm in the middle of it and then I decide to add an image? I don't want to quit the Mail. Is there a way to attach an image (file) directly from there? I'm a really perceptive guy but in this case I cannot see any icon with a paper clip symbol or anything similar that would suggest that I can attach something.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press and hold anywhere on the text area. A contextual menu will appear. 
If there is no text on the message, the option to the right will say "Insert Photo or Video".

[image]

If there is text, the options will be "Select", "Select all", "Paste" and an arrow. Clicking the arrow will show "Insert Photo or Video"

[image]

Click on it and select the Photo or Video you would like to attach.

Comment: Thank you Jaime! Every time I was punching right arrow, the contextual menu was disappearing! Seems that I finger is too big. OK. Now I'm more precise and it works. EDIT: Exactly - thanks for the screenshots. :)

Comment: I wish there was a way to attach anything, not just pictures.

Comment: It's funny how things are so simple with iOS yet they are very difficult to find! Thanks for this great answer